# join 2 table with SUM and Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i have 2 table one is buy_table and another is sale_table. in this query in this query i will have to use SUM , group by and date also but i am not able to understand and its showing som error

```
//buy table
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | product_id | quantity | total_price | date       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 5        |   500       | 2014-12-05 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2          | 5        |   500       | 2014-12-15 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1          | 5        |   500       | 2014-12-01 |

//Sale_table
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | product_id | quantity | total_price | date       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 5        |   1800      | 2014-12-05 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2          | 5        |   500       | 2014-12-15 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 3          | 5        |   500       | 2015-01-01 |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 3          | 5        |   500       | 2015-01-01 |
```

i need like this.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | product_id |buy_quantity| buy_total | sale_quantity|sale_total 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 10       |   1000      |    5         |  1800
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2          | 5        |   500       |    5         |  500
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 3          | 5        |   500       |    10        |  1000
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what have you tried? what is the error? what is the database? MySQL<>sql-server

Comment: How did you get `buy_quantity` and `buy_total` for `product_id=3`?

Answer (score 0):

The id column in your results doesn't make sense if you want to show buy/sale by product.

To ensure you always get all the products, you need to use your product table as the driving table (Assuming you have a product table)

```
select
p.product_id,
(SELECT SUM(b.quantity) FROM buy b WHERE b.product_id = p.product_id) as buy_quantity, 
(SELECT SUM(b.total_price) FROM buy b WHERE b.product_id = p.product_id) as buy_total,
(SELECT SUM(s.quantity) FROM sale s WHERE s.product_id = p.product_id) as sale_quantity, 
(SELECT SUM(s.total_price) FROM sale s WHERE s.product_id = p.product_id) as sale_total 
from product p
```

Comment: thats littile bit working but problem is in buy_table there is 2 product and sale table 3 products. from this code i am getting only 2 products details which is in buy table

Comment: I've amended my answer

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have a product table? If the previous answer almost worked, then this one has to work

Comment: Were you referring to the missing ( ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
A.ID,A.PRODUCT_ID,A.BUY_QUANTITY,B.SALE_QUANTITY,A.BUY_TOTAL,B.SALE_TOTAL,A.DATE
(select id,product_id,sum(quantity) as buy_quantity,sum(total_price) as 
buy_total,date  from buy_table group by product_id) A INNER JOIN (SELECT sum
(quantity) as SALE_quantity,sum(total_price) as SALE_total FROM SALE_TABLE  group by product_id) B 
ON A.PRODUCT_ID=B.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: this is not valid SQL

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that you mistyped the third row in buy table and you meant to type 3 in `product_id` and the `id` column in the desired result set is just a serial which is not relevant to any data. The below query might be the answer for your inquiry:

```
-- Simluating your tables
DECLARE @buyTable AS TABLE (id INT, product_id INT, quantity INT, total_price INT, date DATE)
DECLARE @saleTable AS TABLE (id INT, product_id INT, quantity INT, total_price INT, date DATE)
INSERT INTO @buyTable
VALUES(1, 1, 5, 500, '2014-12-05'), (2, 2, 5, 500, '2014-12-15'), (3, 3, 5, 500, '2014-12-01')
INSERT INTO @saleTable
VALUES(1, 1, 5, 1800, '2014-12-05'), (2, 2, 5, 500, '2014-12-15'), (3, 3, 5, 500, '2014-01-01'), (4, 3, 5, 500, '2015-01-01')
-- Simluation stops here

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.product_id) AS id, b.product_id, buy_quantity, buy_total, sale_quantity, sale_total FROM
(
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS buy_quantity, SUM(total_price) AS buy_total FROM @buyTable
    GROUP BY product_id
) b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sale_quantity, SUM(total_price) AS sale_total FROM @saleTable
    GROUP BY product_id
) s ON s.product_id = b.product_id
```